# Transitions class (state machine) get a list of possible transitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a `ActiveRecord::Transitions` in Rails 3 and have my state machine defines as:

```
state_machine do
 state :initial # first one is initial state
 state :active
 state :disabled

 event :activate do
   transitions :to => :active, :from => [:initial, :disabled]
 end
 event :disable do
   transitions :to => :disabled, :from => [:initial, :active]
 end
end
```

How do I see a list of available transitions for a current object and state?
For example if I have a `@product` in state "active" it should tell me

- "disabled" is the only state available, or
- "disable" is the only event available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any obvious way to enumerate possible-next-states, but you can query the available events like this:

```
YourClass.state_machines[:default].events_for(:active)
 => [:disable]
```

(If you have more than one state machine there will be additional members in the `YourClass.state_machines` Hash)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is now more relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794147/7693)

Basically - you have access to `@product.state_evants`, `@product.state_transitions` and `@product.state_paths`