# In state_machine, how do I find which events are valid from the current state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I am using Aaron Pfeifer's [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem in my Rails3 app -- it's nifty.

How do get a list of events are legal in the current state?  By this, I do *not* mean `my_model.state_path.events` which returns *all* events transitively traceable from the current state -- I want only those that are available in the current state.

I'm pretty sure I'm simply overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaron himself answered the question on the PluginAWeek:Core group mailing list:

> Hi -  You can see the list of helper methods that get generated for
>   each  state machine in the docs for the #state_machine macro under the
>   heading "Instance Methods": 
>   http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine...
>   Here you'll notice a few instance methods which should help you along:
>
> - state_events - Gets the list of events that can be fired on the 
>     current object’s state (uses the unqualified event names)
> - state_transitions - Gets the list of transitions that can be made on
>     the current object’s state
> - state_paths - Gets the list of sequences of transitions that can be 
>     run from the current object’s state  Hope this helps!  Best,  Aaron